How to Configure Fluent Bit for Multiline Java Application Logs in Kubernetes
Actually my application produces the logs this like
2024-06-20 18:31:55 INFO  o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:532 -   - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-06-20 18:31:55 INFO  o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:554 -   - Completed initialization in 10 ms
2024-06-20 18:31:55 INFO  c.e.s.HelloController:17 -   - INFO: Accessed /service1
2024-06-20 18:31:55 WARN  c.e.s.HelloController:19 -   - WARN: Accessed /service1
2024-06-20 18:31:55 ERROR c.e.s.HelloController:20 -   - ERROR: Accessed /service1
2024-06-20 18:31:55 INFO  c.e.s.HelloController:21 -   - Starting application...
Application version: 1.0.0
Initializing components...
Component 1 initialized successfully
Component 2 initialized successfully
Application started successfully!
2024-06-20 18:32:20 INFO  c.e.s.HelloController:17 -   - INFO: Accessed /service1

However, I am encountering issues when Fluent Bit forwards these logs from EKS to Datadog, where multiline logs are not being processed correctly. as shown in below:
logs coming in Datadog

Jun 21 14:49:30.805 devops-test Component 2 initialized successfully

Jun 21 14:49:30.805 devops-test Application started successfully!

Jun 21 14:49:30.804 devops-test Component 1 initialized successfully

Jun 21 14:49:30.804 devops-test Initializing components...

Jun 21 14:49:30.804 devops-test Application version: 1.0.0

Jun 21 14:49:30.000 devops-test - Starting application...

Jun 21 14:49:30.000 devops-test - ERROR: Accessed /service1



Iam excepting logs like 

Jun 21 14:49:30.805  devops-test 

Component 2 initialized successfully
Application started successfully!
Component 1 initialized successfully
Initializing components...
Application version: 1.0.0
- Starting application...

Jun 21 14:49:30.000 devops-test

- ERROR: Accessed /service1

I will show the fluent-bit configuration:
apiVersion: v1
data:
  custom_parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name custom_log_parser
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<severity>\S+)\s+(?<class>\S+):(?<line>\d+) - \[%X{dd\.trace_id}\s+%X{dd\.span_id}\]\s+-\s+(?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

    [MULTILINE_PARSER]
        Name docker_multiline
        Type regex
        Flush_Timeout 1000
        Rule "start_state" "/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/" "cont"
        Rule "cont" "/^(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/" "cont"
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Daemon Off
        Flush 1
        Log_Level info
        Parsers_File /fluent-bit/etc/parsers.conf
        Parsers_File /fluent-bit/etc/conf/custom_parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server On
        HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port 2020
        Health_Check On

    [INPUT]
        Name tail
        Path /var/log/containers/devops-test*.log
        Tag kube.*
        Mem_Buf_Limit 5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines On
        Multiline.Parser docker_multiline, docker, cri

    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Merge_Log On
        Keep_Log Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On
    [OUTPUT]
        Name stdout
        Match *
        Format json_lines
    [OUTPUT]
        Name datadog
        Match *
        Host http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com
        TLS On
        TLS.Verify On
        apikey ..............
        dd_service devops-test
        dd_source java
        dd_tags env:devops-test



how to resolve the multiline log issue using fluent-bit ??
This configuration output is shown below:
2024-06-22T11:05:34.398905129Z {"date":1719054334.242247,"time":"2024-06-22T11:05:34.242247291Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"2024-06-22 11:05:34 INFO  c.e.s.HelloController:17 -   - INFO: Accessed /service1"}
2024-06-22T11:05:34.398966062Z {"date":1719054334.242759,"time":"2024-06-22T11:05:34.242759106Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"2024-06-22 11:05:34 WARN  c.e.s.HelloController:19 -   - WARN: Accessed /service1"}
2024-06-22T11:05:34.398970525Z {"date":1719054334.242982,"time":"2024-06-22T11:05:34.242982297Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"2024-06-22 11:05:3
ERROR c.e.s.HelloController:20 -   - ERROR: Accessed /service1"}
2024-06-22T11:05:34.398974795Z {"date":1719054334.243565,"time":"2024-06-22T11:05:34.243565391Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"2024-06-22 11:05:34 INFO  c.e.s.HelloController:21 -   - Starting application..."}
2024-06-22T11:05:34.398978627Z {"date":1719054334.243724,"time":"2024-06-22T11:05:34.243724284Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"Application version: 1.0.0"}
2024-06-22T11:05:34.398981503Z {"date":1719054334.243729,"time":"2024-06-22T11:05:34.243729104Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"Initializing components..."}
2024-06-22T11:05:34.398985014Z {"date":1719054334.243734,"time":"2024-06-22T11:05:34.243734008Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"Component 1 initialized successfully"}
2024-06-22T11:05:34.398988466Z {"date":1719054334.243738,"time":"2024-06-22T11:05:34.243738105Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"Component 2 initialized successfully"}
2024-06-22T11:05:34.399003101Z {"date":1719054334.243742,"time":"2024-06-22T11:05:34.243742179Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"Application started successfully!"}


You misunderstood the java_multiline plugin, I think. It only detects multiline stack traces, not random logs. You could define a custom multi-line parser that considers entries without a timestamp as continuation lines.

I changed the code but still getting like that
